# Android pre-filled localized database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm building an app which should have a pre-filled content from database but that content is should be localized properly.

I saw solutions with puting SQL into assets dir and run files that match current locale and fall back to "en_US" when not found.

Another solution would be adding an extra column with ENUM for locales and put an index on it.

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: a down vote? some people should not have access to the internet :(

Comment: It seems a national sport these days, to downvote as soon as possible... :(

Comment: Upvoting to offset the unexplained downvotes.